# How to avoid multiple labels in matplotlib in pyton?

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

So, I have two lists with 170 elements in them. So I want to make a plot with them and also have a label.

```
df = pandas.read_excel('MyData.xlsx', sheet_name='Data')
listRe = []
listkS = []
listRe.append(df['Re'])
listkS.append(df['ks+'])
plt.plot(listRe, listkS, c='b', marker='.', markersize=5, label="Experimental Data")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

With this code I get 170 labels on my graph. But I only want 1 label. What is the problem here ?

edit: so I want to change the question here.

```
df = pandas.read_excel('MyData.xlsx', sheet_name='Data')
listRe = []
listkS = []
listRe.append(df['Re'])
listkS.append(df['ks+'])
d, = plt.plot(listRe, listkS, c='b', marker='.', markersize=5)
plt.legend([d], ["data"])
plt.show()
```

When I do this it gives me an error which is "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)" . What is wrong here ? How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Just do `plt.plot(df['Re'], df['ks+'], c='b', marker='.', markersize=5, label="Experimental Data")`

Comment: it doesnt work actually.

Comment: What's in `listRe` and `listkS`? Strings? I assume the one label you want is `Experimental Data`. Do you want that to label an axis? The whole plot? To remove the labels you don't want you likely need to use methods like this: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html.

Comment: If you include a screenshot of the graph with circles around the labels you don't want, it would be easier for people to understand what you're trying to do. It would also be better if your example code included a small amount of data so people could run it themselves. Good luck!

Comment: they were floats. i cant include a screenshot because of my reputation. I am trying to plot some points and want a legend for them which says experimental data. but for every point there is a legend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the edited part of my question was solved. It was about reading data from excel. It was reading the null cells also, so it was giving value error. When I took only the correct cells it worked. Be careful while taking data from excel.